# Lebesgue integrability of $\ f$ and $\ f^{-1}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\ f:\ X\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is a measurable function.

If $$\int_{X} f\ d\mu<\infty\ $$
 and $$\int_{X} \dfrac1f\ d\mu<\infty $$ Show that $\mu(X)<\infty$.

Comment: What can you say about $f + \frac1f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel Fischer's hint is right on target: 
$$2\mu(X)\le \int_X (f+f^{-1}) <\infty$$
Or, if one feels like using a (mis-)named result, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields 
$$\mu(X) =\int_X f^{1/2}f^{-1/2} \le \sqrt{\int_X f}\sqrt{\int_X f^{-1}}<\infty$$